# I changed associated products, but no change is displayed frontend

Tags: magento-1.9, configurable-product, associated-products

I use magento 1.9 and i have a problem:
I do changes in associated products (with saving in associated products) of a configurable product but none of changes is displayed frontent. 
If a do save in the configurable product then all changes of associated products are displayed in frontend.
In admin i see the changes in associated product of configurable.
Is that a magento feature? or nothing else?

Updated:
Also i have another problem may be related with previous. I have an another shoes with sizes  38,39,40,41. After a customer order the stock of 38 is 0 (out of stock). I see that in admin. But in frontend 38 is in available option, but if someone choice it , a message dispayed that product size is out of stock. Then i go to admin and do save in that configurable product and then the size 38 disappeared in frontend.

May by i have problem with stock update and only with save in configurable products the stock become updated.

Any idea?

Comment: I dont understand exactly. Can you be more specific or provide a screenshot?

Comment: I have a shoe with available sizes 39,40,42. Size 41 is out of stock and isn't displayed in frontend (correct). Then enter configurable product in admin and in associated product tab , i enter in simple product with size 41 and change the stock (in stock) and do saving the simple associated product. Then i reload the frontend page of product but 42 isn't display. the size 41 was displayed only after i done saving at configurable product. Is that correct?

Comment: Make sure product with size 42 in stock. Beacuse displayed in frontend only in stock associated options

Comment: @Abdul Product with size 42 is in stock. But nothing is displayed before i do save in configurable product. The problem is that without saving in configurable product size 42 isn't displayed in frontend

Comment: but product size 42 is already associated configurable product?

Comment: @Abdul yes it is. it is from past, but it was out of stock. I edit associated product to do it instock, but nothing is displayed in frondend before i do save and in configurable product